# Need to remove first three alphabets from a string in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I have data like this.

```
ABC1234
K234657
M465789
XYZ8498
1234XYZ
```

I need to strip first three characters from them if all of them are alphabets. Result should be

```
1234
K234657
M465789
8498
1234XYZ
```

How can i do this using PROC SQL

Comment: What does PROC SQL have to do with this question? Why limit the solution to SQL?

Comment: sql... what?  Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring

```
SELECT 
Val = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(V,0,3) not like '%[0-9]%'
  THEN SUBSTRING(V, 4, len(V) - 3)
ELSE V

END
FROM TEST
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
Declare @tempTable as Table
(
    MyData VarCHar(200)
)

Insert Into @tempTable (MyData) Values
    ('ABC1234'),
    ('A001234'),
    ('12345678')


Select
    CASE WHEN MyData LIKE '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]%' THEN SUBSTRING(MyData, 4, 200) ELSE MyData END
FROM
    @tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `patinex`.

```
select case patindex ('%[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]%', val) when 1 then substring(val, 4, 8000) else val end
from (
    values
     ('ABC1234')
    ,('K234657')
    ,('M465789')
    ,('XYZ8498')
    ,('1234XYZ')
) t(val)
```

Comment: It looks like valid SQL.

Comment: PATINDEX is NOT a SAS function implemented in Proc SQL.  PATINDEX is in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FINDC() function to find where the first non-alphabet character is. So if your variable is named STR the function call would look like this:

```
findc(str,,'ak')
```

So when the result is 4 you want to remove the first 3 characters.

```
data want ;
  set have;
  if 4=findc(str,,'ak') then str=substr(str,4);
run;
```

Typically in SQL code you would use `CASE` to do conditional logic.

```
create table want as 
   select case when (4=findc(str,,'ak')) then str=substr(str,4) else str end as str
  from have
;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @string as varchar(100)

set @string = '1234XYZ'

if isnumeric(substring(@string, 1,1)) = 0 and isnumeric(substring(@string, 2,1)) = 0 and isnumeric(substring(@string, 3,1)) = 0 
    select substring(@string, 4,len(@string)-3)
else
    select @string
```